# R Loop Through Excel Sheets

Tags: r, loops

Imagine You have Excel sheet with Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3. All sheets have one variable X1 with 10 random values in COlumn A.

Is there a way to loop this process,

```
Sheet1 = read_excel("myfile.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet1")
Sheet1.Mean = mean(Sheet1$X1)

Sheet2 = read_excel("myfile.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet2")
Sheet2.Mean = mean(Sheet2$X1)

Sheet3 = read_excel("myfile.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet3")
Sheet3.Mean = mean(Sheet3$X1)
```